# Tkinter not working in cmd (working in IDLE)

Tags: python, cmd, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to display a directory selection dialog box (for getting a path and then for saving downloaded stuff).The code runs fine in IDLE but when i try to run it in CMD i get this error

`NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined`

I am using tkinter for gui.

Code Snippet

```
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Using Python 3.4.3. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: The patch I applied in 3.4.4 and 3.5.1 appears to have fixed this particular issue in that code run from IDLE now in 3.5.2 or 3.6.0a2 results in the NameError, as it should.  The tracker issue is https://bugs.python.org/issue25507.  I hope to finish this issue of IDLE running code that should fail, because of hidden imports, before 3.6.0.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for the info!

Comment: My answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806673/importing-from-a-package-in-idle-vs-shell/38808437#38808437 describes how to fix this in existing releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `from tkinter import filedialog` only imports the `filedialog` module from `tkinter`. If you want the usual Tkinter stuff, you have to import that too. I'd recommend `import tkinter as tk` and then referring to it with e.g. `root = tk.Tk()` so you don't just dump everything into the global namespace. Or, if you really just want the root object, use `from tkinter import Tk`.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: Dude you are god! Thanks a ton!